# Cleaning up MySQL Query, Wordpress wp_postmeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
SELECT 
  post_id,meta_key,meta_value 
FROM
  wp_postmeta 
WHERE 
  post_id > 3185 AND
  meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' OR 
  post_id > 3185 AND
  meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' OR
  post_id > 3185 AND
  meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' 
ORDER BY post_id 

post_id meta_key                meta_value
3186    _shipping_first_name    Joe
3186    _shipping_last_name     Svelnys
3186    _shipping_postcode      06040
```

This is the output data. I'm trying to format it like

```
Order  FName  LName    Zip    
3186   Joe    Svelnys  06040
```

Any ideas? I'd really appreciate it.

Here's a Sqlfiddle to help
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select post_id as OrderNo, 
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = w.post_id and meta_key = '_shipping_first_name') as FName,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = w.post_id and meta_key = '_shipping_last_name') as LName,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = w.post_id and meta_key = '_shipping_postcode') as Zip
from wp_postmeta w where w.post_id > 3185 group by post_id
```

Fiddle here:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3606/10

Comment: Appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
select wp1.post_id, wp2.meta_value as FName, wp3.meta_value as LName, wp1.meta_value as Zip 
from wp_postmeta wp1 
left join wp_postmeta wp2 
    on wp1.post_id = wp2.post_id 
        and wp2.meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' 
left join wp_postmeta wp3 
    on wp1.post_id = wp3.post_id 
        and wp3.meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' 
where wp1.post_id = 3185 
    and wp1.meta_key = '_shipping_postcode';
```

Something like this?

Comment: that returns 
3186 06040 Joe \N

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution looks like this, but a version of the solution similar to J33nn's should work just as well - and may even be quicker!

```
SELECT post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' THEN meta_value END) fname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' THEN meta_value END) lname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' THEN meta_value END) zip
  FROM wp_postmeta 
 WHERE post_id > 3185 
 GROUP   
    BY post_id;
```